# Compiling OpenCV 2.4.5 in xcode 4.6.2 for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv

I've been trying to build opencv framework for `ios` using the steps in the readme file in the ios directory:

Assuming that your build directory is on the same level that opencv source,
From the build directory 
run

```
../opencv/ios/configure-device_xcode.sh
```

Then from the same folder invoke

```
xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release -target ALL_BUILD

xcodebuild -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release -target install install
```

I have followed these steps and the scripts say they have completed successfully but the folder which should contain the completed framework is incomplete.

Can anyone confirm that they have successfully built the opencv ios framework `2.4.5` with `xcode 4.6.2`?

I'm not sure but could be related to this question:
[Command `xcodebuild` failing to copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092597/command-xcodebuild-failing-to-copy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now a Python script which will generate the framework with much less effort. From the `ios` directory, run

```
./build_framework.py <outputdir>
```

where `<outputdir>` is the path to where the framework will be built.

Comment: Excellent - thanks. First attempt failed because my <outputdir> was in my opencv folder. I moved it outside and worked fine.